# Why is the CSS not applying to my HTML anymore?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm new to programming and for some reason the CSS is not applying to the HTML. It was working before and I don't know what I did to make it stop applying. I want the text to be centered in the middle of the page, but it keeps staying on the left side. Could someone please check my code really quick and tell me what I did wrong? Thank you!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sub-header {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7)), url(assets/contact-sub.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-header h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.contact {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.reachme {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

td {
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hours {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center
}

.hours {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .sub-header {
    height: 35vh!important;
  }
  .reachme {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
}


}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  <div class="reachme">
    <h4>Reach Me At</h4>
  </div>
  <table class="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>(123)456-7890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>email@gmail.com
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>

<section class="hours">
  <aside>
    <p>Let's connect! ↓
    </p>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: seems to be fine in the snippet?

Comment: Do a hard refresh in your browser

Comment: You maybe have a file cached in your browser - clear browser cache or try a different browser to see if things change.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell without seeing the entire HTML file.  Is the CSS even being loaded?  Does your HTML file have proper `<head>` and `<body>` sections, and does the `<head>` section call for the CSS with a tag resembling `<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-style.css">`?  Is your CSS file in the same directory as your HTML file?  (Or are you doing all this within some kind of web-based tool that doesn't expect an HTML `<head>` section?)

Have you tried to test whether *any* of the CSS is active by adding some simple rule like `body { background-color: green; }`?  If that doesn't work, then something more basic must be wrong.

(I also can't help but notice that extraneous `}` at the end of your CSS; browsers are sometimes graceful about ignoring little things like that, but now and then they can break things.)